# sql rows columns

Tags: sql

Hi    suppose     there     is     a     field     called     Description

Description      which     has     values
    A
    B
    C

I      want      the     desired     output      as
Desc1      new     column     to      have     first      value     of description      i.e      A
Desc2     new     column     to     have     second     value      of       description     i.e     B
Desc3     new     column     to     have     second     value      of    description     i.e     C

that      is     the     values     of     description     field     into separate     column     decsription1     description2 d    escription3     new     fields

Can     anyone     help

Comment: Please      format      your      question      properly.

Comment: its jus that desciption field values A B C should be fetched in new column desc1 should have first value desc2  should have second value desc3 hould have third value and so on

Comment: Please format your quesion properly.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code to extract 3 columns from string
You can make you LEFT, RIGHT and SubString function of SQL Server

```
declare @name varchar(50) ='A B C'

select left(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name)) as desc1,
substring(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name)+1, len(@name)-(CHARINDEX(' ', @name)+1)) as desc2,
right(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name)) as desc3
```

Comment: is there any simple sql select statement?

Comment: You can create user defined function for this and pass string and split Delimiter.